# How to get file name from asp:FileUpload and display in a Label using ASP.NET and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using a `<asp:FileUpload>` to upload a PDF file to my web page. But after clicking on browse the window opens, and once I select a file and click on `Open` i want to get the file name and display it in a `Label`. What function should I use in `ASP.NET` to do this? I tried the `OnLoad`, `OnUnload`, `OnDataBinding`, etc. in the `<asp:FileUpload>` but nothing works. Can someone suggest me a solution for this?

My code is as below:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="labelFilename" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Once I select a file and click open the file name should be displayed in the label.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fileUpload').change(function () {
            var path = $(this).val();
            if (path != '' && path != null) {
                var q = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                $('#labelFilename').html(q);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the file name(server side) by using following code snippet

```
string file_name=fileUpload.FileName.ToString();
```

You can access the filename on client side using following code snippet

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

            $("#fileUpload").change(function () {  

                var FileUpload = $("#fileUpload").val();  
   ... }
 }
```